# Is there a path which continues from here?

Tags: elden-ring

I'm in Stormveil Castle on the westside where I've dropped down from the top to here. Is there a path which continues from here? I only see an illusionary ground which disappears when I drop down. Can't see anyway to continue.
[image: Illusionary ground]

Comment: Is there a reason to assume there is a path? If so, can you [edit] your question to add that information?

Comment: @Joachim Games in the souls-series are notorious for having hidden/sneaky routes. There appears to be some sort of road with an arch/gate, so I think it's natural to assume there is a path. Since the OP "falls through the map" per se could mean they can't access that path from their current location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landing on the illusionary ground and falling through it will make you survive the fall. But I think doing a ground attack was what killed me. So probably as long as you don't do a ground attack you should survive.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump without problems, the illusory floor will not hurt you, and you will be able to reach a small secret area.